# Create a ZIP archive with Maven

Tags: maven-2, zip

I followed the answer for how to create a ZIP archive in Maven here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2514677/1395165 
and have a couple of follow-up questions:

**ZIP contents to exclude directory:**

As in the example I have:

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/export</directory>
    <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
</fileSet>
```

In the ZIP I get

```
src
  export
     Dir1
     Dir2
```

but I only want to have

```
Dir1
Dir2
```

in the ZIP. Is that possible?

**Output file name**

The output file name is created with a .zip extension. Is it possible in Maven to override the extension to something else (say .abc)?

Answer (score 17):

The outputDirectory option can be used to change the directory within the assembly that the files are output to - this should do what you need:

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>bin</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/ScriptedBuild/rConnect/extract/</directory>
        <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: You definitely pointed me in the right direction. However I had to do this `<outputDirectory>..</outputDirectory>` to achieve what was asked. Did I miss something?

Comment: If you don't set `baseDirectory` then it defaults to `${project.build.finalName}` like `App-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT/` inside the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

set includeBaseDirectory to false - see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had tried that and a lot of variations of baseDirectory. I've posted my zip.xml as an answer because it didn't seem to want to post in the comment area.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<assembly ...
  <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
```

And

```
<fileSet>
  <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
```

That will put all files in the root of the zip file.

BaseDirectory sets the directory inside the zip to use for all files, like it prepends it to all paths. That way when you upzip it without making a directory first, it doesn't pollute your current working directory.

OutputDirectory sets the directory inside the zip file. BaseDirectory is still 'prepended' to this. So BaseDirectory = `/project-1.2.3` and OutputDirectory `/src` will create `project-1.2.3/src/` inside the zip.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html

> **baseDirectory** String  Sets the base directory of the resulting assembly archive. If this is not set and includeBaseDirectory == true, ${project.build.finalName} will be used instead. (Since 2.2-beta-1)
>
> **outputDirectory**   String  Sets the output directory relative to the root of the root directory of the assembly. For example, "log" will put the specified files in the log directory.