# Maven pom to zip config files from GitHub and jars from artifactory

Tags: maven, github, pom.xml, artifactory

**Requirement**:

- Need to push config files and jars from artifactory to UCD for deployment.
- Config files are present in GitHub repostiory.
- Jars (not needed for build but needed to start application in UCD) are present in artifactory.

What would be the general process to follow, in order to copy config files from github and download/copy jars from artifactory and package everything in a zip file to push to UCD?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider:

- [the maven download plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741965/6309) to get the files you need from an URL (like a GitHub repository or an Artifactory one)
- [the maven assembly plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10907183/6309) to build your archive
- configuring on [UCD side the source of your Nexus package to deploy](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/7850/nexus-maven-plugin-to-push-artifacts-into-udeploy/), although there is a [urbancode plugin maven-ibmucd](https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugin/maven-ibmucd/) which could be handy (not tested)

Comment: Note to self: That was my **22000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 131 months), 6 months after the [21000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856158/6309). Before that, [20000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915541/6309), [19000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49421565/6309), [18000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860745/6309), [17000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703956/6309), [16000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40698777/6309), [15000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37539529/6309) [14000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34327286/6309), ...