# Creating zip file in package phase

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

For Creating the zip file through maven i followed this : [Creating a zip archive of the maven "target" directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514429/creating-a-zip-archive-of-the-maven-target-directory) and i am using this maven command **assembly:single** .

Is it possible to create zip file in the **Package** phase only(means using **Clean package**) ??

Comment: Your referred page uses the `package phase` already as  `<phase>package</phase>`.

Comment: but zip file is not created during that phase.so only "assembly:single" i am using.

Comment: Where do you place the `maven-assembly-plugin` configuration? Under the `<plugins>` or `<pluginManagement>` ?

Comment: <pluginManagement> <plugins> <plugin> maven-assembly-plugin </plugin></plugins> </pluginManagement> .This is the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add the `<plugins>` after the `<pluginManagement>` as the following example: -

```xml
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
          <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Please see [POM Reference: Plugin Management](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) for further information. I hope this may help.