# How to make a single folder after zip

Tags: maven

After zipping the folder structure is like this

con-1.0-SNAPSHOT-Zipped inside this folder there is con-1.0-SNAPSHOT-Zipped inside it there is a folder named as B folder and then inside it there are the files.

Is it possible to make less folders , i mean can only a single folder be made inside which the files should be there ?

Comment: post ur plugin info.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514429/creating-a-zip-archive-of-the-maven-target-directory

Comment: i have used the maven-assembly-plugin , version 2.2.1

Comment: First use up-to-date version of maven-assembly-plugin (2.4) furthermore add you descriptor and your pom file.