# Maven assembly create jar with dependencies and then create zip and tar.gz file

Tags: java, maven

I would like to do the following with the maven:

1. Pack my code & dependencies to uber jar
2. Attach a script to it (either Windows script or Linux script)
3. Put both script and jar to a folder
4. Crate zip for Windows AND tar.gz file for Linux

Is this possible in Maven using assembly or any other plugin?

Comment: As an example take a look [here](https://github.com/khmarbaise/supose/tree/master/supose-assembly).

Answer (score 1):

i would split this into two projects and for convenience a parent module, like this:

```
projectX
|- codeproject
|- packingproject
\- pom.xml
```

**codeproject**:

- Nothing special here, just create your über-jar

**packagingproject**:

- save your scripts as `src/main/resources/start.bat`
- copy your `codeproject.jar` with [copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html)
- create your zip/tar-file with the [maven-assembly-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2514677/562363)

**parent pom**:

- also, nothing special, just add both modules

**Note**:

be sure to call install on your codeproject so that the jar gets copied to your local maven repository, otherwise you may end with a file not found or an old version of your code.